# Timestamp date variable syntax wrong

Tags: bash

I'm trying to use a variable *Timestamp* to transfer a date into the following date command:

```
Timestamp=Sep 17 16:07:21 2014  

Timestampdate=$(date -d $Timestamp +%s)
```

to get the date in seconds, but I can't get the syntax correct around the `$Timestamp` variable. Any help please?

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate question but the question there will answer this one.

Comment: Thanks again today Etan!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to surround variables with whitespace characters with quotes to keep them together, or else the shell will interpret the space as a word break, changing your meaning.

```
Timestamp="Sep 17 16:07:21 2014"
Timestampdate=$(date -d "$Timestamp" +%s)
```

The auto-splitting of unquoted inserted variables is sometimes useful. For instance:

```
myargs='-t -r -d'
ls $myargs foo bar baz
```

gets inserted on the command line literally as `ls -t -r -d foo bar baz`, in effect allowing a arbitrary arguments to be pulled from a variable.

Comment: Double quotes..... but I was sure I'd tried those too. However you're correct I've tried it and it does work. It's been a long, hot day, and I missed it. Many thanks ALL!